# Any example of quickbook online with OAuth2.0 and access all the api

Tags: node.js

I need one help from you. I am trying to create one new sample app in developer.intuit.com which generate in Oauth 2.0.
I want to use quickbook online using nodejs with OAuth 2.0 and access the all API of it.
Is there any example which help me for that??

Answer (score 0):

Try this package - https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-quickbooks

Refer doc here - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0200_dev_guides/0000_overview